# Select a column returned by a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which is returning me about 50 columns. I want to write a query, where I will be able to select a particular column from the list of column returned by the SP.

I tried writing `select RSA_ID from exec(uspRisksEditSelect '1')` But Its throwing me an error.
I think we need to write some dynamic sql for it. But I am new to it.

Comment: It is throwing an error - care to share this error?

Comment: Should exec(uspRisksEditSelect ,'1') return a single value or a table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the results of a stored proc directly - you need to store that into an in-memory or temporary table and go from there:

```
DECLARE @tableVar TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50))  -- whatever your sp returns

INSERT INTO @tableVar
    EXEC uspRisksEditSelect '1'

SELECT RSA_ID FROM @tableVar
```

But there's definitely no need to use dynamic SQL.....

Comment: Does this work with the stored procedure, which has nested EXEC call? for example : msdb.dbo.sp_help_job

Answer (score 3):

You should write a table-valued user function.

Comment: This should have been a comment to the OP because it doesn't answer the question.  It's possible that your suggestion isn't an option.  What if he /can't/ create a TVF?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify your stored procedure, you can easily put number of needed columns as parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetDiffDataExample
      @columnsStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) -- Needed columns
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @columnsStatement + N' INTO ##TempTable FROM dbo.TestTable'
    EXEC sp_executeSql @query
    SELECT * FROM ##TempTable
    DROP TABLE ##TempTable
END
```

In this case you don't need to create temp table manually - it creates automatically. Hope this helps.